# Qunit.JUnitReport where is the xml file

Tags: javascript, junit, qunit

I don't seem to find the report.xml file after I execute my qunit test.  In my test structure - I have the test runner that includes qunit, jquery and css files and after that I include the junit reporter below:

```
 <script src="qunit-reporter-junit-master/qunit-reporter-junit.js"></script>
```

and in my test .js file I have added the below line at the top of the file:

```
var myReport = "C:\Test\myReport.xml"
QUnit.jUnitReport = function(myReport){
    console.log(myReport);
};
```

When I execute the test, the test results show PASS on the browser, but I couldn't find the test result XML file; am i missing something here?

thank you.

Comment: It doesn't create any file, it simply passes an XML string to `QUnit.jUnitReport`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I guess then to get log to file, will have to tell Junit to do it.  I don't know java though so whether learning it is necessary to use Junit.

Comment: Has there been some solution to this? I am having the same problem here, I want the report.xml in a file, not the console.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine was **finally** able to help me with this one!
We used PhantomJS to achieve the following:

- Download PhantomJS from http://phantomjs.org/

  - The folder you downloaded contains 2 folders, *bin* and *examples* (current state)
  - inside the *examples* folder, you find a file called "run-qunit.js"
- We then forged a PHP-Script that calls PhantomJS and the run-qunit.js script:

  [...]
  $value = shell_exec('phantomjs.exe run-qunit.js PATH_TO_TEST_FILE');
  file_put_contents("PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE.xml" ,$value)
  [...]

After that we got pretty nice output into the .xml-file.
Now we just have to figure out how to make Jenkins understand that output ;-)

I hope this answer was of use for you or someone who has a similar problem.